# C# cast type help

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting

I wrote a test method on my inherited Membership Provider object and want to call that method by actually casting up the membership provider to my object. Membership is not of type MembershipProvider. It is the default Membership object.

```
 ((MyMembershipProvider)Membership).Test();
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong here. Does it complie? Does it throw exception?

Comment: You may need to provide more information.  What is the type of `Membership` prior to the attempt to cast?  Are there being any exceptions thrown when you try to cast?

Comment: It says membership is a type not a variable.

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting an exception thrown? What is a Membership in relation to a MyMemberShipProvider?

Comment: @Dietpixel how you define the Membership object?

Comment: Sorry for the terrible description above.

Comment: @DietPixel: Don't say sorry, use the _[Edit]_ link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure it is possible. But if you are implementing custom membership provider, then you forgot to take property `Provider` from your `Membership` object. Like this:

```cs
((MyMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).Test();
```

Comment: You beat me to it, have my +1.

Comment: Where did this mysterious Provider property come from? You must have some domain knowledge into this question!!! Lies!!! +1

Comment: @jason-down Ha-ha, no mystery here, it’s just from ASP.NET / ASP.NET MVC domain and it’s pretty common task for developers to implement custom membership providers :)

Comment: @oddy: I figured as much. I don't do much with ASP.NET since most of my development is with mobile apps or desktop apps.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
((Membership)MyMembershipProvider).Test();
```

I'm guessing here, but I think your MemberShip is the class type and the MyMembershipProvider is a reference to a class (an object). You've just got your cast operands backwards.

In otherwords, you may be trying to do something like this:

```
int myVal = 1;
double mySecondVal = (myVal)double; // fail

double mySecondVal = (double)myVal; // success
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, if the `Membership` object is a `MyMembershipProvider` type, and it has the `.Test()` method. You can check this like that:

```
if (Membership is MyMembershipProvider)
    (Membership as MyMembershipProvider).Test();
```

Comment: You don’t have to use `as` here if you already know `Membership` is a `MyMembershipProvider` (and you’re testing it in the previous line). It just needs casting, like ` ((Membership)(MyMembershipProvider).Test();` But I gues it’s a matter of taste :)